# Cerrar una venta -- pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Hola estoy desarrollando el juego de snake, pero a la hora de jugar y perder la partida se activa una pantalla de game over, que tiene 3 botones: Salir, Guardar y menu primcipal este ultimo se develve al menu principal como lo deberia hacer pero el problema es cuando vuelve a jugar aparece la pantalla del game over. Tambien nesecito quitar la barra de arriba de la ventana.

Voy a pegar el link de github y unas partes del codigo que creo que son las importantes

https://github.com/Dicocha/Snake.git

Esta es codigo del modulo del juego

```
     # Game Over conditions
     if PosicionPersonaje[0] < 0 or PosicionPersonaje[0] > Win_x-10:
        game_over()

    if PosicionPersonaje[1] < 0 or PosicionPersonaje[1] > Win_y-10:
        game_over()

    # Touching the snake body
    for block in CuerpoPersonaje[1:]:
        if PosicionPersonaje[0] == block[0] and PosicionPersonaje[1] == block[1]:
            game_over()
```

Este es el modulo de game over:

```
    # displaying score countinuously
    start_text('Puntuacion: ' + str(Puntuacion), font_P, Blanco, screen_game, 250, 2)

    # Refresh game screen
    pygame.display.update()

    # Frame Per Second /Refres Rate
    FPS.tick(VelocidadPersonaje)

    # Control
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    # Acciones de los botones
    if MenuPrincipal.collidepoint(mx, my):
        if click:   
            main()
```

Gracias y espero sus respuestas, si nesecitan mas codigo me pueden decir y perdon por las tildes.

Comment: Hola, Diego. Tienes que ser lo más conciso posible con el código, pero también tiene que estar lo más completo posible: ahí se echa en falta un bucle `while` de control de eventos, por ejemplo, o una función con un `__init__` u otra parte importante que ayude a comprender lo que hace el código...

Comment: Hola @FranciscoJavier ya edite la pregunta espero que sea mas clara asi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que plantearte rehacer tu código, porque tiene muchas cosas que corregir, empezando por las muchas variables globales, algunas de ellas no declaradas a nivel de función, a pesar de ser reescritas en ella:

La variable `global click` tienes que definirla a nivel de módulo `click = False` y como `global` dentro de cada función en la que la quieras escribir...

Otras veces ocultando a las variables pasadas a la función:

```
def Game(change_to, Direccion, PosicionPersonaje, CuerpoPersonaje, PosicionFruta, VelocidadPersonaje, SpawnFruta):
```

Por otra parte, estás generando tres ventanas diferentes de `Pygame` en vez de usar una sola y regenerar su contenido cuando sea necesario.

Por cierto, para quitar la barra de título debes añadir lo siguiente:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((Win_x, Win_y), pygame.NOFRAME)
```

Tampoco necesitas tener tres bucles `while`.

En fin, son muchas cosas y unas llevan a las otras...

Comment: Tengo que transladar el codigo de juego, puntuacion y game over a fuera de los modulos e insertarlas en el main que va a estar afuera del modulo?

Comment: Para no añadir datos descontextualizados en la respuesta he escrito una hoja con algunas ideas y la he puesto en un pdf online... [Enlace al pdf](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AoLTwhyvvNTKhaNnlp2lxD7fn1rUYQ?e=BauGbh)

Comment: Muchas gracias. :D